# Trying to install gh using brew

Tags: macos, github, homebrew

I have the following vars in place in my Macbook. However when I try to install gh I get the ERROR below:

export HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.com:8080

export HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.com:8080

wferreir@QQN6DR99LY ~ % brew install gh

Warning: git 2.36.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 2.36.1, run:
brew reinstall git
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew, skipping update!
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core, skipping update!

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gh/manifests/2.10.1

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 407

Error: gh: Failed to download resource "gh_bottle_manifest"

Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gh/manifests/2.10.1
wferreir@QQN6DR99LY ~ %

Comment: I believe this is caused by an [incident with GitHub Packages](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/gcqz5grcs4z6).

Answer (score 0):

I revolved the issue by configuring a proxy for GIT:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```